# Remove underline selector for tabpageindicator

Tags: android

I am using fragments with tab using sharelockactionbar and viewpage indicator libraray it shows highlighted underline for selected tab but i don't want that highligted line . i am alredy changing tab icon on select tab. how to i remove this underline indicator using tab page indicator tabs.

Comment: Try adding `android.R.color.transparent` as selected color.

Comment: under line is not color it is 9 patch images if i remove images than it shows default blue color drawble line that are written inside lib